# Timber filter logs by tag

Tags: android, kotlin, logging, timber-android

When using Timber, I can see tags being automatically generated, which is nice. However, I can't really access these tags in code. I can only see them in Logcat, but I don't know how to filter them.

I know it is possible to turn on logging for debug builds only:

```
if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
    Timber.plant(DebugTree())
}
```

However, this isn't very useful for me. I tried to do:

```
Timber.plant(Timber.tag("TroublesomeClass"))
```

But I am getting:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot plant Timber into itself.
```

.. which makes no sense at all to me.

Is there any way how to filter Timber logs by the tag?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Filter in the logcat?

Comment: @Arpit Shukla That is an option, but it is not a good option. As the project grows, the logging can get quite heavy. When that happens, Logcat filtering becomes extremely slow even on fast machines. In another project where I use plain old Log I creates custom logger which allows filtering and I love it. So much more productive!

Comment: @Arpit Shukla Also it helps with targetting problematic parts of the project, for which you would like to keep logs even in release version. That way you can have much better error reporting without slowing down the whole app.

Comment: Where do you want to keep the filtered logs?

Comment: @Arpit Shukla Just showing them in standard output is fine. I intend to look at them in Logcat. It truly is "just" about the speed. Logcat is simply too sluggish to use efficiently with larger projects.

Comment: So you want to keep a local list of all logs instead of logging it to logcat and then only show a filtered list in logcat? Is it so?

Comment: @Arpit Shukla No. This is what I am doing with old Logger in Java in another project: https://pastebin.com/YumjB7AZ  This is exactly what I would like to do - but using Timber if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I figured this one out. It is actually really simple. You just need to subclass `Timber.DebugTree` like this:

```
/**
* Custom Timber logging tree allowing to filter logs by Tag.
*/
class FilteringTimberTree(val allowedTags: List<String> = ArrayList(),
                        var filteringEnabled: Boolean = true) : Timber.DebugTree() {

    override fun log(priority: Int, tag: String?, message: String, t: Throwable?) {
        if(!filteringEnabled || allowedTags.contains(tag)) {
            super.log(priority, tag, message, t)
        }
    }
}
```

And then plant the tree in Application class:

```
val allowedTags = arrayListOf("Tag1", "Tag2", "Tag3")
Timber.plant(FilteringTimberTree(allowedTags))
```